# How to create an empty TSV file and how to transfer dataframe to TSV file in Scala Spark?

Tags: dataframe, scala, csv, file, apache-spark

The logic is I have a set of set, let's suppose it's `val Set = {{1,1,1}, {}, {2,2,2}}`. I want to loop this set, if the set is empty, I want to create an empty TsV file, but if it is not empty, I want to use that set to form a dataframe and write that dataframe into a TSV file.

```
Set.foreach(s=>{
  if(s.isEmpty){
    //create an empty TSV file
  }
  else{
    //transfer the set to dataframe(This step is done)
    //write the dataframe into a TSV file
  }
})
```

So I'm wondering if there is an approach to achieve this.

Comment: You need to be specific on your question for others to help! You can do both using dataframe.write.csv(path)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I edited the description to make it more specific.